# std::enable_shared_from_this<> - missing is_shared()?

Tags: c++, c++11

`shared_from_this()` has undefined behavior if object is not shared.

But if shared, it know about the relevant "control block" (Effective Modern C++, Item 19). So why does `std::enable_shared_from_this<>` not add some `is_shared()` function that returns true or false, for object is shared or not?

`std::enable_shared_from_this<>` seems to introduce some kind of dependency inversion. The object depends on the way it is used. But with some `is_shared()` function it at least could "adapt" to mixed mode usage.

Comment: I don't have this problem—all classes of mine that inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` have a non-public constructor and a static method that creates an object and returns it as a `shared_ptr<T>`.

Comment: `std::shared_from_this<>` enables you to get valid shared_ptr to this ptr. It's used inside class(member functions). Think of `class A` with method `foo()` returning `shared_ptr<A>`. You cannnot simply return shared_ptr<A> in A class. Thats why you return such pointer using `shared_from_this()` with inheritance `std::enable_shared_from_this<A>`.

Comment: With `shared_ptr<A>(this)` you would be creating multiple shared_ptrs with separate reference counters. It's the same behavior as you would create multiple shared_ptrs from the same raw pointer.

Comment: Maybe i got something wrong: but std::enable_shared_from_this<> **requires** that the object is owned by std::shared_ptr<> - right? It's not possible to to operate with raw ptr anymore.

Comment: @FrankBergemann I was referring to similar situation as `return shared_ptr<A>(this)` to creating multiple shared_ptrs from same raw pointer.

Comment: @paweldac: i fully understand the requirement for std::enable_shared_from_this<T> and shared_from_this(). But i wonder about no option for the class to serve for raw pointers as well. However, maybe a typedef or using directive should do the job for a **separate** type required to be used with std::shared_ptr<>?

Comment: @FrankBergemann if you want to force only creating shared_ptr of type A. Then create friends factory that returns `shared_ptr<A>` and make all you constructors not accessible from ourside your class(protected, private). Remember to make destructor of class A public.

Comment: @davidbak and in which comment I said something different? I said that not using `shared_from_this()` is like creating multiple shared_ptr to same raw pointer. `shared_from_this()` is returing same shared_ptr with incremented reference counter.